# How can I make only label - sunday font color red? (chartjs, vue)

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvNcG.png)

I want to change only holiday (sunday and saturday) xAxes label color.
I know I can add blow.
But it make all xAxes label color.

I am thinking change label text type = string to object or node list.
and control it by array. but I don't know it will be possible.
Is anybody trying to change chartjs lables?

> ticks: {
>                 fontColor: "#d92736"
>               }